# How to to create a custom logger in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, logging

During an exercise in school we have been tasked with making custom middleware in Express:

> This might be tricky. Make it so that your custom logging middleware
>   also logs out the eventual response status code. For example, after a
>   successful GET request to / you should see:

```
GET / 200
```

I tried this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(chalk.green(req.method, req.url, res.statusCode));
  next();
});
```

It appears to work but then I noticed upon trying a `uri` which doesn't exist I still get:

```
GET /foo 200
```

Does this mean the ***request*** i.e. GET, is working but has nothing to do if the resource is there?

Also how would I implement error handling, in this instance I tried:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(chalk.green(req.method, req.url, res.statusCode));
  }
  next();
});
```

But that didn't work at all!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe inspect on how the morgan module works? You are probably always receiving the statusCode of 200 because you are checking before the request goes to the router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    console.log(chalk.green(req.method, req.url, res.statusCode));
  } else {
    res.on('finish', function() {
      console.log(chalk.green(req.method, req.url, res.statusCode));
    })
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @idbehold! Tried it and it appears to work! Two things could you explain what's happening? I think I get it but might be helpful for others in the future...
Second is the `finish` event some how taking care of the errors  if they occur? I ask because I know it is common to use this `error first` pattern in node....