# How to add express middleware at the end of the chain that gets invoked no matter what (OK/FAIL responses)?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Is there a way to add middleware to the end of an express `app` or `router` chain that gets called to track whether or not the `res` / response was sent  or not?

I mean, regardless of if:

- A response is sent (string, JSON, etc.)
- A static served file.
- No file found in the static folder.
- A *catch-all* callback was reached.
- An error middleware was reached.

### Example

For instance, if I wanted to **log** everything...

whether a response was **successful or not**, *ie: it served a file via a `express.static( ... )` middleware, some data fetched from a DB, or a custom middleware, or again... if it failed / threw an error...*, 
is there a way to invoke a callback at the very end?

So far from what I can understand, it seems like, by design, if a static file gets served successfully (via **express.static**), it doesn't call `next()`, so the chain stops there.

And for any custom-made middlewares using `res.send()`, you normally wouldn't want to call `next()` afterwards since it could cause some undesirable side-effects (errors with headers getting resent).

For error-handlers, that's easier since all unsuccessful responses can be caught here.

But how can it output both successful / unsuccessful responses? Could this be something that should be done without middlewares?

Comment: Have you tried using `app.use((req, res, next) => {console.log(req); next()})` before any other route/static routes registration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to to create a custom logger in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367401/how-to-to-create-a-custom-logger-in-express)

Comment: Have a look at [express-afterware](https://gist.github.com/jrf0110/9328478)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I'm basically trying to log a boolean to indicate whether or not the data was served successfully. Putting an `app.use` at the start of the chain unfortunately just assumes every requests are made successful.

Comment: @tbking that helped! By just using an `app.use` combined with a `res.on('finish', ...)` callback, I can verify the `res.statusCode` on all possible outcomes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution I went with ended up being slightly different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46367888/468206) by **@idbehold**, but in a nutshell, at the very top of the express app middleware chain, I had to hook a callback to the `res` Response object's `finish` event which gets triggered for most (all?) HTTP status-codes I needed to track a successfully served request.

```
app.use( ( req, res, next ) => {
    res.on( 'finish', () => {
        var codeStr = String( res.statusCode );
        codeStr = codeStr[res.statusCode < 400 ? 'green' : 'red'];
        var output = [req.method.green, req.fullUrl().green, codeStr];
        trace( output.join( ' ' ) );
    } );

    next();
});
```

I can now get things like:

[image]

### EDIT

Alright! So provided you also have an error-handler at the "end" of your middleware chain that serves something with an error `404` code, that will trigger the `finish` event on the `res` object.

Example of such an error-handler:

```
app.use( ( err, req, res, next ) => {
    trace( "Error!".red );
    trace( err );

    res.status( 404 ).send(); // Triggers 'finish' on res.
})
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a conceptual difficulty with the asynchronous architecture of node.js and Express for doing this.   I'll describe the general problem and then discuss a few possible work-arounds.

First, each Express handler can be asynchronous.  Thus, it gets called and returns pretty much immediately and nobody outside of that world knows whether it is still waiting for some asynchronous operation to finish before eventually sending its response or if it just failed to do anything.  You literally can't tell from the outside world.

Second, you can monitor a given request to see if it either calls an error handler or if it sends a response.  There is no way to monitor a request handler to see if it just failed to send anything because of the reason above - you have no way of knowing if its still waiting for some asynchronous thing to finish.

So, here's the best I could recommend:

1. Hook `res.end()` to see when it gets called.  This is an indication that the response is now done (whether error or success).  You can see an example of doing that in the [express-afterware](https://gist.github.com/jrf0110/9328478) module that Medet linked in an above comment.  The general idea is that you'd have your own middleware somewhere very early in the chain that overrides `res.end()` so you can see when its called.  That early middleware would just install the override and call `next()` to continue the handler chain.  Then, when the response is finished, your override would see that `res.end()` got called.  This should work for all cases where the response is sent.
2. Then, you still need to handle cases where no response is sent (which is probably due to faulty code since all requests should get a response eventually).  The only way I know of to do that is to implement some sort of timeout for a request.  You can either use a built-in mechanism [`server.setTimeout()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback) or you can implement your own inside your middleware (same middleware as describe in step 1).  Then, after some timeout that you specify, if no response has yet been sent, you would take over and send some error response.
3. Install your own error middlewares early in the chain that will see and log all errors.  Note that `res.end()` will still be called so the behavior in step 1 will still be triggered even for errors (error responses still call `res.end()`).

Comment: I may need to fallback to your recommendation to make sure that I do catch those potential ones that would never get `sent()` (with your `setTimeout` idea), as I imagine the `res.on('finish', ...)` technique I went with probably doesn't handle that case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a piece of code at the end of a request by using the finish event of the response object. The finish event is emitted when the response has been sent to the client and all the data has been flushed to the network.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Request finished');
  });
  next();
});
```

Comment: This was already answered with a very similar code snippet.